# Windows 10 education version too low microphone sound

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have the windows 10 education version and I experience too low microphone volume even though it's set to maximum. I have tried everything but I haven't been able to fix the problem.

Is this related to the windows or perhaps there is a setting somewhere that reduces the microphone sounds?

Comment: Perhaps a missing driver? What model is your computer and your speaker?

Comment: I do not think it's a missing driver. I have tried several mics and others complain that they can barely hear me. Anyway right now I am using my sony earphones and this adaptor: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07RRZYZFV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: See https://www.getdroidtips.com/increase-mic-volume-windows-10 . In particular, there are third-party apps, However, why bother? You state, "I haven't been able to reproduce the problem." Is it no longer an issue, as you state, or is that a mistake?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Sorry for misunderstanding english is not my first language. I meant to say that I havent been able to find a solution to the problem :)

Comment: @csandreas1, no problem! The question will; be edited with your clarification.